# Syntax highlight empty virtual columns

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to include empty virtual columns in a `syn match` group? I want to highlight a block of text as though it's in a terminal window by giving it a black background, but I want the "terminal" to always be 80-columns wide, even if the text in that line is shorter.

I tried `sync match cmdLineOutput '.*\%<81v'` but that only matches if there are actual characters there. I guess I need something to replace `.` which matches characters and empty columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could try playing with colorcolumn:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=black
let &colorcolumn=join(range(1,80), ',')
```

This makes a black background for the first 80 columns, but it makes screen redrawing slower.

See :h colorcolumn for more options.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear about this, but I only want it on certain rows (where the match occurs), so I don't think this will work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `join` and `range`.

Answer (score 2):

As a text editor, there's no need for highlighting beyond the text, so you need to hack it. The already mentioned `'colorcolumn'` works for specific columns, but in all lines in the window; if you need highlighting of specific lines, you can use *signs*. Unfortunately, those highlight *all* columns in the specific lines (and show the sign column in addition).

```
:sign define demo linehl=Search
:exe "sign place 2 line=3 name=demo file=" . expand('%:p')
```

If you really need both specific lines *and* columns, I think you have to add trailing whitespace to those lines, and then you're able to use the normal `:syn match` on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `colorcolumn` option approximately does what you want. Normally, it highlights only a single column, but you can also specify a list of columns. In your case you could emulate what you want by

```
:set colorcolumn=81,82,83,84,85,... (how many you want)
:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=black
```

Comment: I probably wasn't clear about this, but I only want it on certain rows (where the match occurs), so I don't think this will work. Thanks anyway!